# Оптимизация кода с лямбда выражениями. DRY

Tags: java, оптимизация, lambda

В общем есть такой код:

```
private static final Map<Integer, Constrain<CharSequence>>
        minLengthCache = new HashMap<>(),
        maxLengthCache = new HashMap<>();

public static Constrain<CharSequence> minLength(int length) {
    Constrain<CharSequence> cached = minLengthCache.get(length);
    if (cached == null)
        minLengthCache.put(length, cached = string -> string.length() > length);
    return cached;
}
public static Constrain<CharSequence> maxLength(int length) {
    Constrain<CharSequence> cached = maxLengthCache.get(length);
    if (cached == null)
        maxLengthCache.put(length, cached = string -> string.length() < length);
    return cached;
}
```

Как видно, очень некрасиво повторяется. Что порождает кучу опасностей ошибиться при копипасте, а если таких функций будет штук 20 и нужно будет что-то поменять, то можно вообще об стенку убиться.

Первым делом приходит в голову нечто такое:

```
public static Constrain<CharSequence> minLength(int length) {
    return cachedOrNew(string -> string.length() > length);
}
public static Constrain<CharSequence> cachedOrNew(Constrain<CharSequence> newObj) {
    Constrain<CharSequence> cached = minLengthCache.get(length);
    if (cached == null)
        minLengthCache.put(length, cached = newObj);
    return cached;
}
```

Но здесь теряется смысл в кэше совсем. Ведь каждый раз всё равно будет создаваться новый экземпляр объекта, а заодно и его класс, объекта, который должен быть возвращен, если в кэше такого нет.

В принципе я представляю, как это это решить через вложенный класс, `.Class` и рефлексию, но тогда придется отказаться от очень удобного синтаксиса лямбда выражений.

Comment: по-моему, вы изобретаете [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). Что-то вроде `minLengthCache.computeIfAbsent( length, key -> string -> string.length() > key );`

Comment: О. Вы правы. Сейчас посмотрел, я действительно, тот ещё велосипедостроитель ) Но смотрите, в принципе проблема остается, по идее класс всё равно же будет создан. А значит не очень оптимально в том случае всё.

Comment: поскольку функция `key -> string -> string.length() > key` не захватывает переменные извне, jvm может ее оптимизировать, создав только один экземпляр (примерно как вы в своем ответе руками сохраняете фабрику в `minLengthConstrain`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем протестировал я всё это на простеньких бенчмарках. Запускал тест 1000000 и просто считал общее время. Теперь о результатах.

Никакие оптимизации для кэша объектов (Чтобы избежать new) не нужны. Компилятор делает это сам, причем как оказалось работает быстрее самопальной реализации (я почему то думал, что реализовав вручную, будет всё же быстрее, а как бы не так). Не сильно конечно, но надобность делать это вручную отпадает.

Оптимизация лямбда выражения - тоже не нужна. Аналогично скорость просто создания объекта была выше получения его через HashMap и Фабрику. Так что ещё один плюсик в Java, вернее в компилятор )

Comment: Зачем отдельный ответ?

Comment: Ну оба ответа мало связаны между собой, да и тема достаточно широкая

Answer (score 1):

В общем решил проблему вот так:

```
private interface ConstrainFactory<C, P> {
    Constrain<C> create(P param);
}
private static <P, C> Constrain cachedOrNew(Map<P, Constrain<C>> cache, ConstrainFactory factory, P param) {
    Constrain cached = cache.get(param);
    if (cached == null)
        cache.put(param, cached = factory.create(param));
    return cached;
}

public static Constrain<CharSequence> minLength(int length) {
    return cachedOrNew(minLengthCache, minLengthConstrain, length);
}
private static ConstrainFactory<String, Integer> minLengthConstrain = (length) -> (string) -> string.length() > length;
```

Всё решение основывается на том, что есть некий параметр, на основе которого можно генерировать классы. Для меня сойдет, но возможности лямбды по сути не используются, да и выглядит код своебразно - сразу и не въедешь, для чего что нужно. Поэтому вопрос оставляю открытым - может кто покрасивее предложит решение.